# Canceling $.post before completion

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using $.post for uploading files to server. File upload will take sometime based on the size of the file. So what I want to do is to give user the option to cancel file upload ($.post) before the upload completes:

```
var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
$.post('/upload.aspx',
      {file : file},
      function(data){
       //upload completed
      }
   );
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying `XMLHttpRequest` object has an [`abort` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort()-method) on most browsers, so:

```
var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
var xhr = $.post('/upload.aspx',
  {file : file},
  function(data){
   //upload completed
  }
);

// Later if aborting it
if (xhr.abort) {
    xhr.abort();
}
```